# php mysql storing just hours minutes seconds

Tags: mysql, time

I know a typical timestamp in any format readable or otherwise is always equivalent to a date time second day month year etc. However I want to be able to search by hours minutes seconds where the day month year are irrelevant. So I am trying to wrap my head around that ability and what would be the best method of storing time so I can create searches around that alone without m-d-y getting in my way.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html) field type. The [`TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) field type should only be used anyway when you want `MySQL` to update the field when updating the row.

Comment: by "The TIMESTAMP field type should only be used anyway when you want MySQL to update the field when updating the row." you mean that `TIMESPAN` should only be used in the case of the `MySQL` auto update? o.O

Answer (score 0):

`$hour = date("H",$date);` `$minute = date("i",$date);` `$second = date("s",$date);`

and save them on your table as `hour`,`minute` and `second`

Comment: How can this be better in any way than using the dedicated [TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time.html) field that MySQL offers?